# Workbench renders quite slow

Tags: rendering, workbench-render-engine

I'm cutting a project in the blender "Video Editing" tool, and I am working on my rough cut. To be able to send it and watch it outside of blender, I'd like to render it with the "Workbench" renderer.

When I simply hit play in my timeline (and make sure to clear the cache with Ctrl-R) I can watch my cut in real time, it renders immediately.
But when I render my animation with "Render -> Render Animation" it is a lot slower. It is nowhere near real-time rendering. I'd say it takes about half a second for each frame.

I've set the Sampling to "Single Pass Anti-Aliasing" for both, the Render and the Viewport settings but it didn't change much.

Is there something else I'm missing?

My viewport and the rendered version also look identical from what I can see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that using the Workbench renderer was the wrong way to approach it. Using `View -> Sequence Render Animation` was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, I think it's because workbench worked with CPU, but the render will ask for the GPU. However, I don't know what to do to ask for CPU when I use workbench, the only way is use the quick render in view