# Why does Blender reload the assets for each rendered frame even though the assets are the same?

Tags: rendering

I have noticed that for each frame blender takes a noticeably long time doing, what I assume is loading/compiling assets, and takes around 30 seconds on my computer with a large blender project. Is my assumption here correct?

What I would like to know is why this takes so long and why this must be done before every frame even though an animation typically has the same assets the entire time?

I was originally looking for a way to render an animation with view-port-like quality and even though it could manage 1/3 real-time speed in the view port, workbench took 30 seconds per frame. (If you are having the same problem someone answered the question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170324/workbench-renders-quite-slow)). So if the view port can render everything without loading assets every frame why do workbench, eevee, and cycles have to?